# Bottom Part of Software Window Hidden

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, window

I use a software without window resizing on a 17 inch monitor, i find that the bottom part of the window is hidden ie:below the visible portion.

My friend uses a 15inch monitor,he can see the full window.
I have checked the screen resolution and made it to the same as the one in my friend's PC.
Still the bottom part remains hidden below.Why is this?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Is the window draggable?

Comment: @mk117 The window is draggable.I will try to post one soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting the size of the text on the display and/or it could also be the DPI
Check the settings at:

```
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display
```

Compare your friends and yours... Changing DPI will cause a reboot

Comment: Where can i change the DPI

Comment: You can change the dpi under display options... [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/JCVUYg2.jpg)